# Displaying label and button with Objective Oriented Programming and tkinter

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I'm going to make a program with a lot of labels and buttons with OOP. Let say the program I want to make looks like this:

```
p1 = Label(root, bg='lightblue')
p1.place(relwidth=1, relheight=0.5)
p1 = Button(root, text= 'test')
p1.place(x= 0, y= 0)

p2 = Label(root, bg='red')
p2.place(y=200, relwidth=1, relheight=0.5)
p2 = Button(root, text= 'test 2')
p2.place(x= 0, y= 200)
```

To make it more efficient for when I'll make p3, p4, p5, etcetera I wrote the following:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(height=400, width=400)
canvas.pack()

class Display:
    def __init__(self, root, x, y, bg, relwidth, relheight, text):
        self.root = root
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.bg = bg
        self.relwidth = relwidth
        self.relheight = relheight
        self.text = text

    def DisplayLabel(self):
        Label(self.root, self.bg).pack(self.relwidth, self.relheight)

    def DisplayButton(self):
        Button(self.root, self.text).pack(self.x, self.y)


p1 = Display(root, 0, 0, 'lightblue', 1, 0.5, 'test')
p2 = Display(root, 0, 200, 'red', 1, 0.5, 'test 2')

p1.DisplayLabel()
p1.DisplayButton()
p2.DisplayLabel()
p2.DisplayButton()

root.resizable(False, False)
root.mainloop()
```

The idea is that instead of writing every label and button again and again I just write the values I want like in p1 and p2. The code mostly works like expected and i'm able to print individual values of p1 and p2. But everything goes wrong when I try to display the labels and buttons in the program. When I try this part:

```
p1.DisplayLabel()
p1.DisplayButton()
p2.DisplayLabel()
p2.DisplayButton()
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Daniel\PycharmProjects\stockalarm\test.py", line 36, in <module>
p1.DisplayLabel()
File "C:\Users\Daniel\PycharmProjects\stockalarm\test.py", line 27, in DisplayLabel
Label(self.root, self.bg).pack(self.relwidth, self.relheight)
File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3144, in __init__
Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2565, in __init__
classes = [(k, v) for k, v in cnf.items() if isinstance(k, type)]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I display the buttons and labels in the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to specify which parameters your arguments are supposed to set, like you did in your first snippet of code:

```
p1 = Label(root, bg='lightblue')
p1.place(relwidth=1, relheight=0.5)
```

In the second snippet, however, you just put the variables in there with no specification:

```
Label(self.root, self.bg).pack(self.relwidth, self.relheight)
...
Button(self.root, self.text).pack(self.x, self.y)
```

It should be:

```
Label(self.root, bg = self.bg).place(relwidth = self.relwidth, relheight = self.relheight)
...
Button(self.root, text = self.text).place(x = self.x, y = self.y)
```

You also accidentally wrote `pack` instead of `place`.